# Gerar script do banco com estrutura e dados

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Backup é não tenho como fazer, pois depende de permissão da França e etc. Logo, a solução que encontramos aqui foi tentar gerar um script que copie não só a estrutura das tabelas, isso eu já faço e fiz, mas tipo um INSERT carregando todos os dados para esse script. Isso é possível? Tentei pelo DTS do Sql Server, mas só copia estrutura.

Comment: Bem a solução que eu encontrei aqui, foi gerar o select das principais tabelas, salvar em csv e depois em casa, carrego pra dentro das tabelas os dados. Essa foi a solução encontrada até agora.

Comment: existem soluções melhores para isso, vou postar uma

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma boa solução para gerar a estrutura de um banco de dados e importar os dados é utilizar o próprio **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**, ele dá todo o suporte para isso.

1. **Primeiro vamos gerar o script de toda a estrutura da base.**

Abra o **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**, conecte-se na sua base e clique com o botão direito nela

Depois vá em Tarefas -> Gerar Script, conforme a foto acima, isso se estiver em português.

Clique em próximo.

Depois escolha o que você vai querer exportar, tudo ou só algumas coisas especificas, no meu caso só tem tabelas criadas, normalmente não recomendo recria as permissões de usuários, já que nem sempre eles vão está no servidor novo e isso gerara erro.

Por final é só escolher onde vai querer salvar o script.
Normalmente eu salvo em uma nova janela do SQL.

Após isso é só criar seu banco de dados com o script gerado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Agora vamos importar os dados

Antes de iniciar esse passo é bom desabilitar todas as constraints do banco, para não dá problemas na hora de importar os dados, pois ele não verifica as dependências de FK antes, para saber qual tabela importar primeiro, e isso pode dá problemas, depois é só ativar novamente.

Para desabilitar as Constraints é só rodar o script abaixo:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all'
```

Clique com botão direito, no banco de dados que você criou e depois em "importar" dados.

Clique em "avançar", após isso vai para uma tela para você parametrizar os dados da fonte de dados que você ira importar as informações.

No seu caso em fonte de dados escolha **Sql Server Native Client**, que no caso é uma conexão com um base dados SQL Server. Em nome do servidor passe informe o o ip/dns do servidor, ou o que você utiliza para conectar a ele. Preencha os dados de autenticação e por fim escolha a base de dados que você ira puxar as informações.

Agora você vai para a tela de parametrização da base de dados do destino, a parametrização dela e igual a anterior, só que no caso com os dados do banco de dados do destino, que no seu caso é o banco criado a através do seu script.

Escolha a opção "Copiar dados de uma ou mais tabelas ou exibições" e em "avançar".

Selecione todas as tabela e clique em "editar mapeamentos".

Deixe a opção "Habilitar inserção de identidade", essa opção vai manter os identitys do banco antigo quando você migar os dados, após isso clique em "OK"

Com todas as tabelas que você deseja migrar as informações selecionadas clique em "avançar" e depois em "concluir"

Após importado os dados reabilite todas as constraints:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT all'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem, acho que eu não consegui me expressar bem. Eu estou na empresa, cheio de restrições e preciso terminar em casa a alteração nos fontes e para isso preciso ter o banco funcionando. Gerar o script das tabela e procs já fiz. Só falta levar pra casa os dados e é aí que vaca tosse. Precisava gerar um script de insert com todos os dados nesse Insert e isso não consigo. Então, o que eu fiz, rodei o select das principais tabelas, peguei o resultado e exportei para .csv e em casa eu importo tudo das planilhas geradas. Essa solução é a que eu tenho no momento.

Comment: @pnet É só vc criar uma base no seu localdb da maneira que eu informei e criar o backup dela e levar para casa

Comment: Jeferson, bom dia. Backup aqui é proibido, nenhum usuário consegue criar. Precisa de permissão da França e não tenho tempo para isso. Hoje termina meu contrato e só falta a alteração no fontes em VB6, o que preciso desse backup para rodar em casa. Tô fazendo com planilha. Gerei 15 planilhas, que são as que eu preciso. Tudo que envolve Backup e Download, nem adianta. Não conheço VB e tá osso debugar.

Comment: @pnet eu n estou falando para vc fazer um backup do servidor e sim da sua maquina, instale um sql server na sua maquina com localdb, aí nele vc vai ser SyAdmin e vai poder fazer tudo na sua maquina, depois é só seg]uir os passos acima para erar um banco na sua maquina, após isso só fazer o backup dele

Comment: Entendi Jeferson, a política da empresa aqui é muito amarrada, os consultores aqui não tem mobilidade pra nada. Nada pode ser instalado nada, backpeado. Não se permite download de nenhuma espécie. Tive que instalar uma VM para rodar o VB6, pois na máquina não dava para instalar a versão do Crystal dos fontes. Mas a sua solução, vai ficar pra mim como estudo e outras oportunidades. Vou marcar sua resposta, mas vou ficar com as planilhas ou perder umas 2 horas e montar `select insert...` de todas as tabelas.